# NGRX effect incorrectly triggering multiple actions

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, effects

I have the following NGRX effects defined in a single class. The `loadPage$` effect works fine. The `loadSection$` effect works, but for some reason is triggering both the SetPages action and the SetSections action even though I'm only returning the SetSections action. Any ideas?

**Effects**

```
  @Effect()
  loadPages$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<GetPages>(GET_PAGES),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.loanService
        .getPages()
        .pipe(
          pluck('data', 'pages'),
          tap((pages: Page[]) => pages[0].active = true),
          map(pages => new SetPages(pages))
        );
    })
  );

  @Effect()
  loadSections$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<SelectPage>(SELECT_PAGE),
    switchMap((action: SelectPage) => {
      console.log('loadPageSection$::action:', action);
      return this.loanService
        .getPageSections(action.payload)
        .pipe(
          pluck('data', 'pageSections'),
          map(sections => new SetSections(sections))
        );
    })
  );
```

**Actions:**
All the actions defined in a single file.

```
export const GET_PAGES = 'GET_PAGES';
export const SELECT_PAGE = 'SELECT_PAGE';
export const SET_PAGES = 'SET_PAGES';
export const SET_SECTIONS = 'SET_SECTIONS';

export class GetPages implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_PAGES;
}

export class SelectPage implements Action {
  readonly type = SELECT_PAGE;

  constructor(public payload: string) {
  }
}

export class SetPages implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_PAGES;

  constructor(public payload: Page[]) {
  }
}

export class SetSections implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_SECTIONS;

  constructor(public payload: Section[]) {
  }
}

export type LoanActions = GetPages | SelectPage | SetPages | SetSections;
```

**Reducers:**
When I put a console.log under SET_PAGES and SET_SECTIONS, I see both instances logged during the loadSection$ effect.

```
export function loanReducer(state: LoanState = initialState, action: LoanActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_PAGE:
      const pages = [ ...state.pages ];
      deactivatePage(pages);
      activatePage(action.payload, pages);
      return { ...state, pages };

    case SET_PAGES:
      return { ...state, pages: [ ...action.payload ] };

    case SET_SECTIONS:
      return { ...state, sections: [ ...action.payload ] };

    case GET_PAGES:
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**EDIT adding active/deactivate functions**

```
export const deactivatePage = (pages: Page[]) => chain(pages).find(page => page.active).set('active', false).value();

export const activatePage = (id: string, pages: Page[]) => chain(pages).find(obj => obj.id === id).set('active', true).value();
```

The action is triggered from a button click inside a custom component:
`this.store.dispatch(new SelectPage(page.id))`

Comment: The pages array holds objects like { id:1, label:'Label', active:false }. `deactivatePage` looks for the object where active is true and sets it to false. `activatePage` looks for the object in the array where the id's match and sets the active property to true. I figured since I made a copy of the pages array before using it in those functions, that would be ok.

Comment: If these are pure functions that’s fine. After each `ofType` can you put a `tap((act) => console.log(“effect”, act))` and do a search for wherever the actions are dispatched

Comment: Tested by commenting out the `deactivatePage` and `activatePage` methods. Still strange behavior but different. A button click is what triggers the `loadSection$` effect. After commenting out the functions, SetPages only triggers on the first click. Then each subsequent click only triggers SetSections.

Comment: Can you post code dispatching the action and the deactivatePage, activatePage code?

Comment: Added to original post as an  edit

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way I'm using the store on the component. In the component I have a property `pages: Observable<Page[]>`. in ngOnInt I have `this.pages = this.store.select(state => state.pages)`. On the component template I'm using the array of Pages like so: `*ngFor="let page of (pages | async)"`

Comment: Are you using redux devtools (chrome)? Can you see what actions are dispatched and in what order? Selectors shouldn’t be triggering actions. Idea here is to follow the path action, effect, action, reducer, selector for every action and see if they are behaving as intended. Common issue is one action triggering another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit. I'm using a GraphQL backend and the Apollo client in my Angular app to query the server. I was using the Apollo client's `watchQuery` method to fetch the data.

According to the `watchQuery` documentation

> As you know, Apollo.query method returns an Observable that emits a result, just once. Apollo.watchQuery also does the same, except it can emit multiple results. (The GraphQL query itself is still only sent once, but the watchQuery observable can also update if, for example, another query causes the object to be updated within Apollo Client's global cache.)

When toggling the active flag on the data, it must trigger the `watchQuery`'s cache to be udpated thus triggering the other Ngrx effect. Converting my `watchQuery` to a plain `query` solved the issue.